# How to use BeautifulSoup for Webscraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the subject titles of all the forum posts on this website. I am not sure how to go about this as the HTML format of the forum website is not what I am familiar with.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://thailove.net/bbs/board.php?bo_table=ent'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#I don't think this is correct, but not sure on how else to to do this...
containers = page_soup.findAll("td",{"class":"td_subject"})


for container in containers:
subject = container.a.font.font.contents
#similarly not sure this is correct     
print("subject: ", subject)
```

Please let me know what I should do. Also keep in mind that the website is in Korean but can be easily translated into English if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good until you get to the `for` loop, you should be acessing `container.a.contents[0]` to get the subjects, and the `print` function should be inside your `for` loop:

```
for container in containers:
    subject = container.a.contents[0]
    print("subject: ", subject)
```

---

Running the script then:

```
>>>     
subject:  
                    미성년자도 이용하는 게시판이므로 글 수위를 지켜주세요.                    
subject:  
                    방콕의 대표 야시장 - 딸랏롯파이2                    
subject:  
                    공항에서 제일 가까운 레드썬 마사지
.......
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That seemed to fix my problem. If you dont mind, do you also know how to be able to scrape all the pages in the forum? I tried looking online and can't find a proper solution.

Comment: You can try/look for iterating over the `["href"]` contents